# Compiling vsftpd on CentOS7, getting "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcap" error

Tags: compiling, make, vsftpd

I am in the process of compiling vsftpd, but keep getting this error:

```
[alex@lab vsftpd-3.0.3]$ make
gcc -o vsftpd main.o utility.o prelogin.o ftpcmdio.o postlogin.o \
privsock.o tunables.o ftpdataio.o secbuf.o ls.o postprivparent.o logging.o \
str.o netstr.o sysstr.o strlist.o banner.o filestr.o parseconf.o secutil.o \
ascii.o oneprocess.o twoprocess.o privops.o standalone.o hash.o tcpwrap.o \
ipaddrparse.o access.o features.o readwrite.o opts.o ssl.o sslslave.o \
ptracesandbox.o ftppolicy.o sysutil.o sysdeputil.o seccompsandbox.o \
-Wl,-s -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 

./vsf_findlibs.sh

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcap

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [vsftpd] Error 1
```

I installed libpcap 1.9.0, yet the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're building code from source, you need the `libcap.so` unversioned shared library.  These are typically provided as part of the corresponding `-devel` package. If you're not sure of the package name, you can run something like:

```
sudo yum install /usr/lib64/libcap.so
```

Although in this case, the answer is that you simply need to install the `libcap-devel` package:

```
sudo yum install libcap-devel
```

Comment: That makes sense!  However - I should have mentioned this in my first post - I am working on a system that is not connected to the Internet.  Hence me downloading the necessary library tar files and transferring them onto the target system manually.  On the target system, I then run make, which leads me to the error.

Comment: I don't think that changes the nature of the error or the solution. Download the libcap-devel package, transfer it to the target system, and install it. However, you should also be able to create a symlink to the existing versioned library, like `ln -s libcap.so.2 /usr/lib64/libcap.so`.